# Docker image discards files, Sonatype Nexus involved

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, nexus

Sorry if the title is a little vague but I need to find the real culprit.

I have this setup:

-a git repository called MyRepo.

-a Jenkins instance that auto-builds MyRepo. On post-build steps there's a simple script that executes:

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$1
docker build -t server.com:5000/MyRepo:$branch .
docker push server.com:5000/MyRepo:$branch
```

-The server.com:5000 is the Nexus instance. Here all docker images are saved and can be pulled by docker-compose installations.

-The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/webapp
COPY package.json ./
COPY start_http_server.sh ./
COPY site ./site
COPY resources ./resources
COPY node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./start_http_server.sh"]
```

What I'm seeing is that the final docker image I pull from Nexus doesn't have some files, eg. this is the original structure of resources folder:

```
/resources/awesome/js
/resources/awesome/css
/rseources/awesome/bower.json
/resources/awesome/scss
```

and the docker image is totally missing the js folder.

So, to debug I added in Dockerfile "RUN ls -la resources/awesome/" before and after the "CMD ["./start_http_server.sh"]" line.
I then watch Jenkins build logs and the output of the command is correct, all folders are there.

So is the issue Nexus side? Is there any cache or something similiar that Nexus uses and avoids updating contents?

**EDIT:** To be more clear, the docker image gets correctly updated, only some files/folders don't get included or updated.

Comment: Maybe it is not updating your image. Could you add build number on your tag. And check after that. `$branch-$currentBuild.number`

Comment: Are you sure you are pulling the latest image? Maybe there is some issue in the image only.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, but it does update all other than some files. I edit the post.

Comment: Are this resources built in other stage? it can be the case that if build in other stage and then run the docker build in other, the execution is done in different agents so you would need to stash the files and unstash before execution

Comment: Yes they're built in other stage, but the docker build is run when every resource is already there. Maybe I don't understand, can you explain better the stash thing? Do you need me to give more details?